# Вывод информации в соответствующие поля ввода

Tags: php, ajax

Требуется реализовать вставку в поля ввода отталкиваясь от названия (`title`).
Когда ввожу какое-нибудь название, под полем ввода появляются варианты, кликаю на какой-нибудь, и он подставляется в поле ввода. Требуется сделать, чтобы при клике на какой-либо из вариантов подставлялась информация и в другие поля ввода, помимо названия.

###### entry.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#title').on('input', function() {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if (search != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../vendor/search.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        search: search
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#title_list').html(response);
                        $('#title_list').fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#title_list').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.title_item', function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $('#title').val(title);
            $('#title_list').fadeOut();

            var author = '<?php echo $row['author']; ?>';
            var publicationType = '<?php echo $row['publicationType']; ?>';
            $('select[name="publicationtype"]').val(publicationType);
            $('input[name="author"]').val(author);
        });
    });
    if (search != '') {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/vendor/search.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                search: search
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#title_list').fadeIn();
                $('#title_list').html("");
                var titles = JSON.parse(response);
                for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    const $titleItem = $("<div class='title_item'>" + titles[i] + "</div>").click(titleSelect.bind(null, titles[i], author, publicationType));
                    $('#title_list').append($titleItem);
                }
            }
        });

        function titleSelect(title, author, publicationType) {
            $('#title').val(title);
            $('#title_list').fadeOut();
            $('select[name="publicationtype"]').val(publicationType);
            $('input[name="author"]').val(author);
        }
        var delay = 500;
        var timeoutId;
        $('#title').keyup(function() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                var search = $('#title').val();
            }, delay);
        });
    }
</script>
<form method="POST" action="vendor/zanes.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">
        <div class="parent">
            <td>
                <img id="preview" onclick="openModal(this);">
                </br>
                <input type="file" name="file" onchange="previewImage(this)">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Название:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                <div id="title_list" style="text-align: center;"></div>
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Тип издания:</label>
            <select name="publicationtype">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Однотомное издание">Однотомное издание</option>
                <option value="Многотомное издание">Многотомное издание</option>
                <option value="Собрание сочинений">Собрание сочинений</option>
                <option value="Периодическое издание">Периодическое издание</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Авторы и составители:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="author">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Под редакцией:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="compedit">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Место:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="place">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Год:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="year">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Издательство:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="publisher">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Количество страниц:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="countpages">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Архив:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="archive">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>ББК:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="BBK">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Инвентарный №:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="inventnumber">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Количество экземпляров:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="numbinstances">
            </td>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="label">
            <label>Кому выдано:</label>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="lasttaker">
            </td>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 20px;">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Сохранить">
        </div>
</form>
```

###### search.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['title']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM infprintedit WHERE title = '$title'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $info = array(
            'publicationType' => $row['publicationType'],
            'author' => $row['author']
        );
        echo json_encode($info);
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```